# Installation of mclust package v5.4.6 on R v4.0.1 on Ubuntu v20.04 hangs

Tags: r, installation, package, freeze, mclust

Upon executing 'Rscript -e "install.packages('mclust')"` with R 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, the process hangs during package preparation.  Any idea how to fix or debug this issue?

**ENV:** R v4.0.1, GCC v9, Ubuntu v20.04

**CMD:** Rscript -e "install.packages('mclust')"

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/mclust_5.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2877519 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘mclust’ ...
** package ‘mclust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dEscXG/r-base-4.0.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c dmvnorm.f -o dmvnorm.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dEscXG/r-base-4.0.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dEscXG/r-base-4.0.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c mclust.f -o mclust.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dEscXG/r-base-4.0.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c mclustaddson.f -o mclustaddson.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o mclust.so dmvnorm.o init.o mclust.o mclustaddson.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-mclust/00new/mclust/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response on [R-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2020-May/003175.html) for a similar issue, I figured this issue is due to a bug in the pthread-based versions of Blas and Lapack libraries.

Until the bug is fixed, the workaround is to use *libopenblas-openmp-blas* and *libopenblas-openmp-lapack* libraries.

There are two ways to achieve use these libraries.

1. Uninstall the pthread-based version of the libraries and install the openmp-based version of the libraries.
2. Switch to openmp-based version of the libraries via `update-alternatives`.  This can be done via `sudo update-alternatives --config <name>` command with  being *liblapack.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu* and *libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu*.